# Rails Dynamic Background Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the below view in my rails app but id like to make it neater/dryer so is there a way to make the background images as an inline style and move the image file path into a rails helper method so that I don't have CSS in my view.

### View

```
<%= link_to '#', class: "slide_#{slide.id}" do %>
  <span class="<%= "slide_text_#{slide.id}" %>"></span>
<% end %>

<style type="text/css">
  <%= ".slide_#{slide.id}" %> {
    background-image: url('<%= slide.mobile_background.url %>');
  }
  <%= ".slide_text_#{slide.id}" %> {
    background-image: url('<%= slide.mobile_text.url %>');
  }

  @media only screen and (min-width: 568px) {
    <%= ".slide_#{slide.id}" %> {
      background-image: url('<%= slide.desktop_background.url %>');
    }

    <%= ".slide_text_#{slide.id}" %> {
      background-image: url('<%= slide.desktop_text.url %>');
    }
  }
</style>
```

### What i'm trying to achieve

```
<%= link_to '#', style: { background-image: "#{something}" } do %>
  <%= content_tag :span, style: { background-image: "#{something}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you could inline the background image with `background: url(data:image/gif;base64...` but i don't think that it will make it any nicer